Design Rationale on why AspNet MVC Project template includes jQuery script at the bottom
In any page that is served to your browser from an Asp Net MVC web application with Razor pages, the page is first built up by razor, on the server side, by taking the _layout.cshtml page and then slotting in the ordinary.cshtml page into the _layout.cshtml page.
The standard AspNet Mvc project already has jQuery bundled into the project and it can be seen on line 38 (commented below) of the _layout.cshtml file when looking at a new project template. Depending on what .NET version you choose, your code may look slightly different.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody() //INSERT PAGE CONTENT
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") //JQUERY BUNDLE
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

The problem with the jquery bundle being at the bottom is that jquery code will be unrecognised and fail to run, either in the parent layout file, or the child ordinary.cshtl file that gets inserted in line 31 (see comment) where @RenderBody() is called.
The solution is to simply move line 38 to the very top of the <body> section. If the solution is so simple and yet so opposite to the template provided, that leaves me asking:
What design rationale did the Microsoft engineers follow to place the jQuery bundle at the bottom of the file where, for me, "it clearly doesn't work", or what obvious best practice am I contradicting for me to simply adapt the template given?
